# Codeigniter - Centos 6 - PHP - <?= e <?php

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos

Eu tenho instalado no meu Windows 7 o xampp para desenvolver uma sistema em CodeIgniter. Beleza, sem problemas.... eu utilizo as tags `<?= $variavel; ?>`, para imprimir algo na view ... funciona que é uma beleza.

Contudo, recentemente, eu mudei para o CentOS 6, instalei o PHP 5.3.3 e coloquei o meu sistema do CodeIgniter para roda e percebi que ele apresentava alguns erros... quebrei e quebrei a cabeça, e verifiquei que o problema estava na abertura do php na view `(<?= ... ?>)`, pois quando eu mudei para `<?php echo $...; ?>`, funcionou!

Porque isso?

É alguma versão do PHP? ou o que?

Porque se eu tiver que mudar todo o meu código.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!